# local extrema in an open interval of piecewise function

Tags: calculus

i think for a point to be local max it should be higher than its neighbors in the domain...and it isn't [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDaRL.png)necessarily higher than all the domain since we call it local max and not glabal max...so i think local max exist at the point of discontinuity for Q.57... but my teacher doesn't agree plz sb help me by giving a logical answer....

Answer (score 1):

In 57(a) there is a local maximum at the discontinuity.

In 57(b) it is a local minimum.

Your reasoning is correct, and your teacher is in error.

This can be seen by “covering up” all of the graph except for the part over a sufficiently small open interval $U=(x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon)$ around the domain point $x_0$ where the discontinuity occurs. For all $x\in U$, it is true that $f(x)\leq f(x_0)$ in 57(a) and $f(x)\geq f(x_0)$ in 57(b).